# Ionic 2 - Mobile Application - RAM Dump Showing the list of all API calls

Tags: debugging, ionic2, penetration-testing, frida

We have a mobile application which makes several HTTP calls using "[Advanced-HTTP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http)" plugin.

While doing a Pen-Testing using Frida, it shows the whole API details including the Login-API details.

Is there a way to clear this memory such that once the API call is complete we can clear the RAM ?

Pasting the portion of RAM dump file.

> u0_a86 /data /system/bin/sh CordovaHttpPlugin
>
> CordovaHttpPlugin948874770 https:XXXXXXX/validate_login username
>
> XXXXX.com password Userpass001$ Cookie X-API-KEY
>
> ecdb025b-0142-427a-98cf-XXXXX Content-Type application/json userToken
>
> 0420a400-3770-2757-f351-XXXX

Comment: you want to add this as part of anti-debugging/reversing technique ?

Comment: I will flag under reversing techniques. Thanks

Comment: ur question is not clear

Comment: either you hook glibc#free and start free the heap (with some hacks) or pivot the stack and override the stack with NOPs.. provide more info